# Subir archivos a proyecto spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo almacenar archivos subidos mediante formulario dentro del directorio static de un proyecto spring boot.

Comment: He encontrado un videotutorial muy bien explicado, además de tener el proyecto de github para descargr. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guyFi0AxrBA&t=22s Espero que os sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

en Spring hay un [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) que trata especificamente eso, también puedes encontrar la implementación en [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files)

Puedes ver los detalles en los links que indiqué, pero lo fundamental es hacer un controlador que maneje la subida de archivos:

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

private final StorageService storageService;

@Autowired
public FileUploadController(StorageService storageService) {
    this.storageService = storageService;
}

@GetMapping("/")
public String listUploadedFiles(Model model) throws IOException {

    model.addAttribute("files", storageService
            .loadAll()
            .map(path ->
                    MvcUriComponentsBuilder
                            .fromMethodName(FileUploadController.class, "serveFile", path.getFileName().toString())
                            .build().toString())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    return "uploadForm";
}

@GetMapping("/files/{filename:.+}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Resource> serveFile(@PathVariable String filename) {

    Resource file = storageService.loadAsResource(filename);
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\""+file.getFilename()+"\"")
            .body(file);
}

@PostMapping("/")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                               RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    storageService.store(file);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
            "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

    return "redirect:/";
}

@ExceptionHandler(StorageFileNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleStorageFileNotFound(StorageFileNotFoundException exc) {
    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}

}
```

Un formulario que sirva como interfaz para el usuario y que llame al controlador creado anteriormente:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>

<div th:if="${message}">
    <h2 th:text="${message}"/>
</div>

<div>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
        <table>
            <tr><td>File to upload:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li th:each="file : ${files}">
            <a th:href="${file}" th:text="${file}" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

y una clase ejecutable

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(StorageProperties.class)
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Bean
CommandLineRunner init(StorageService storageService) {
    return (args) -> {
        storageService.deleteAll();
        storageService.init();
    };
}
}
```